# Customize the text of the PickList buttons of PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, picklist

I would like to know if anyone who has faced this has been able to change the text of the buttons of a picklist.
Sometimes due to accessibility problems we may need change it for do this requirement.

The selection buttons of a picklist appear with icons but in the primefaces documentation I don't see how they can be changed text or if it is not possible.

[Updated: I am using Primefaces **version 6.2**]

[image: picklist]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `labelDisplay="inline"` property.

```html
<p:pickList ...
            labelDisplay="inline"/>
```

This will use the default properties of a supported language. See for example the [English properties](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/83638c927cd9b41543bd90ace9e0b3ec5ee2be49/primefaces/src/main/resources/org/primefaces/Messages_en.properties#L34-L41).

[image]

You can customize the labels like:

```html
<p:pickList ...
            addLabel="Voeg toe"
            addAllLabel="Voeg alles toe"
            removeLabel="Verwijder"
            removeAllLabel="Verwijder alles"
            labelDisplay="inline"/>
```

or override the properties. See

- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/primefaces/src/main/resources/org/primefaces

See also:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/picklist

Comment: Very good job @Jasper de Vries, it's the solution I've been looking for. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: thanks, I have verified it and it works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same, and my solution was as follows:

Using **CSS stylesheet** you can change the content with the `content:'yourText'` property.
Then you just have to disable with the `display:none` property the background image of the icon that is in one of the button's span tags. And add the text in each button with the content property.

The interesting thing would be to be able to prepare it for multi language. I think that through JavaScript it could be done.

I leave the example with the solution using the PrimeFaces web showcase.

```
.ui-picklist-buttons .ui-button-text.ui-c {
    display: none !important;
}
.ui-picklist-buttons .ui-button-icon-left {
    display: none !important;
}
.ui-picklist-button-add::after {
    content: 'Add';
}
.ui-picklist-button-add-all::after {
    content: 'Add all';
}
.ui-picklist-button-remove::after {
    content: 'Remove';
}
.ui-picklist-button-remove-all::after {
    content: 'Remove all';
}
```

Note: I also increased the width of the buttons to make them look good in the image, although I have not included it in the capture or in the css code.

[image: buttons selection custom of PickList]

Comment: This can be used if your PrimeFaces version is too old and does not support inline.