PrimeFaces PickList custom localization
I have a picklist like this one:
<div class="card">
    <h5>Advanced</h5>
    <p:pickList id="pojoPickList" value="#{pickListView.countries}" var="country"
                itemValue="#{country}" itemLabel="#{country.name}" converter="#{countryConverter}"
                labelDisplay="inline"
    >

        <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available</f:facet>
        <f:facet name="targetCaption">Starting</f:facet>

        <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{pickListView.onTransfer}" update="msg"/>

        <p:column style="width:94%">
            <div class="flex align-items-center">
                <span class="flag flag-#{country.code} mr-2" style="width: 30px; height: 20px" />
                <h:outputText value="#{country.name}"/>
            </div>
        </p:column>
    </p:pickList>
</div>

The buttons are labeled "Move to Target", "Move all to Target" and so on. I want to change the labels for English and for other countries. How do I go for that? I found documentation here and here, but they don't point me to where to start overwriting the default translations. I also found this question, but the addLabel, addAllLabel, ... attributes were removed in PrimeFaces 14.
Edit: The possible duplicate was edited afterwards to better answer this question. My description already contained a link to it and the explanation why it doesn’t answer my question. It still doesn’t, see comment section.

This question is similar to: Customize the text of the PickList buttons of PrimeFaces. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've modified the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086529/customize-the-text-of-the-picklist-buttons-of-primefaces

I’ve tried what you suggest in your updated answer and what the documentation suggests. It looks simple enough, but no matter where I put e.g. ‚PrimeFaces.locales[„en“][„aria“][„ moveToTarget“]=„My label“‘ the label doesn’t change. I tried ‚
@JasperdeVries you may want to update your answer in that other post for PF14+ to include the info below.

I just created a PF test reproducer and it's working for me.

Just add this script to your page and change any language you want.  Once you get it working move all of this to a stefan-locales.js file and just load that file with a normal <h:outputScript>
This overrides those labels for English EN locale.  Obviously you can do the same for others.
  PrimeFaces.locales["en"] = $.extend(true, {}, PrimeFaces.locales["en"], {
    aria: {
      moveAllToSource: "Move All to Source",
      moveAllToTarget: "Move All to Target",
      moveBottom: "Move Bottom",
      moveDown: "Move Down",
      moveToSource: "Move to Source",
      moveToTarget: "Move to Target",
      moveTop: "Move Top",
      moveUp: "Move Up",
    },
  });


Simply doing PrimeFaces.locales["en"].aria.moveAllToTarget = "My moveAllToTarget"; works for me.

I was looking at the wrong language code. I had to append the country ("xx_XX"). Thanks.
